# Find all solutions of $z^i = i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to find all the solutions of the equation $z^i = i$.

This is my attempt :

$$z^i = i \implies e^{i \log(z)} = e^{i \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi\right)} \implies \log(z) =\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi \implies z = e^{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi\right)}$$

Is this correct ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: How did you get $z^i = i$ implies $z = i^{-i}?$ Check your calculations in this step.

Comment: I suppose they raised both side to $i$, $(z^i)^i = i^i$, then $(z^i)^i = z^{i \cdot i} = z^{-1}$ @Dr.Sundar

Comment: Note that we have $$\log(i)=\log(|i|)+i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)$$ You wrote that $$\log(i)=1+i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n\right)$$ which isn't correct. If you fix this error you'll get the two answers to match up.

Comment: Oh yes ! Silly me . I have changed the question a little. Could you please take a look again ?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to add $+2\pi n$ in the second equality, since the RHS is still $i$, It would be better $$z^i = i \implies e^{i \log(z)} = e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} \implies \log(z) =\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi \implies z = e^{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi\right)}$$ since in the second implication is where you really use the periodicity of $\exp$.

Comment: Yes! Makes sense. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Assume that $z \in \Bbb{C}, z \neq 0.$

Express $z$ as $re^{i\theta } ~: r \in \Bbb{R^+}, \theta \in \Bbb{R}.$

Further, assume that $r = e^{\alpha} ~: \alpha \in \Bbb{R}.$

Then, $z^i = e^{i\alpha} \times e^{(i^2)\theta} = i = e^{i\pi/2} \times e^{0}.$

So, you have two constraints that have to be satisfied:

- $e^{i\alpha} = e^{i\pi/2} \implies$ 
  $\alpha$ has form $\pi/2 + 2n\pi ~: n \in \Bbb{Z}.$
- $e^{(i^2)\theta} = 1 = e^0 \implies \theta = 0.$

Therefore, the satisfying set is

$$\{z = e^\alpha ~: \alpha = \pi/2 + 2n\pi, ~n \in \Bbb{Z}\}.$$